# Selecting a MySql table

Tags: mysql, variables

I have a situation where I am able to choose from multiple tables in a MYSQL database. At any given time I only need to access one table.

Can I put the name of the table inside a variable and then set that within the query? Such that when I want to change the table, I only need to update a variable?

I am thinking kind of like this:

Instead of:

```
$order = "SELECT * FROM 2FieldForm ORDER BY ID";
```

do this:

```
$table = mysql_select_table("2FieldForm");              
$order = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY ID";
```

Now I am not sure if `mysql_select_table` is even valid, but I hope it gets the idea across!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL is simply a string, so have the table name inside a variable and execute the query using `mysql_query()`

```
$table_name = "users";

$order = "SELECT * FROM `".$table_name."` ORDER BY `ID`;";

mysql_query($order) OR DIE(mysql_error());
```

Be sure to add quotes to your table name and field in order to make sure it's properly interpreted by the database. The semi-colon at the end isn't necessary, but helps.

Comment: Sorry nope that is not doing it for me - even copy and pasted your code and changed the table name.

Comment: Yup I just got it fixed - my bad, I had my credentials set to my online database instead of my local one - Thanks @AustinAllover for the error update:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$table = "2FieldForm";
$order = "SELECT * FROM `$table` ORDER BY ID";
```